# Keep proguard copy of obfuscated files while releasing with eclipse

Tags: android, proguard

Sometimes I get error stacktraces that are difficult to catch because when Proguard obfuscates it also merge some private methods and then while doing a retrace I don't have the exact line that is causing the error.

My question is if there is a way, while doing the exported signed apk with Eclipse, to preserve the obfuscated class files that are packaged in classes.dex.
That way with the obfuscated class files I will be able to deobfuscated them and see better what code is merged and figure where can be the error of the stacktraces.

Answer (score -1):

You need to save the mapping.txt file for each version you release, and you can then use it to de-obfuscate the traces with the 'retrace' command (or just lookup names in mapping.txt manually, line numbers don't change):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html#decoding

Comment: I know how to deobfuscate using retrace. My problem is that current retrace don't give me enough information due to merged function.

Comment: Oh, sorry missed that. Don't know of a way to save the classes with Eclipse, you might be able to do it with Ant where you have more control over build steps. You might want to specify the `-dontoptimize` option to ProGuard though, that will keep it from merging code.